# How do you distinguish between two spacetime metrics?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

How do you know if there exists a proper transformation from one metric to another?
I know that sometimes you can check if the Weyl tensor is zero or not, or in a simpler case if one is a vacuum solution and the other is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240898/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coordinates vs. Geometries: How can we know two coordinate systems describe the same geometry?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240898/)